# Breaklinks for reference citation are not working in hypdvips

Tags: hyperref, links, dvips, hypdvips

There are reference citation entries that span more than one line. Since I compile with LaTeX -> PS -> PDF, the links created by hyperref are not correctly displayed in the output file (pdf). To fix this issue, I added `\usepackage{hypdvips}` in my preamble. But I am not getting the links (at the same time I am getting links for toc that span more than one line)

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[draft=false,dvips,ps2pdf=true,colorlinks,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=false,unicode=true,pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[emptypagelabels=false]{hypdvips}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\Hy@backout}[1]{}
\providecommand*{\backrefsetup}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The second breakthrough was the development of the semiconductor laser.
Demonstrations of laser action\enlargethispage{12pt}
in semiconductors were reported in \citet*{Hall1962}, in \citet*{Nathan1962}, in
\citet*{Holonyak1962}, and in \citet*{Quist1962}.
All of the papers were independently submitted within a span of less than three months in 1962. The practical breakthrough of the first
continuous-wave room-temperature semiconductor laser was reported by
\citet*{Alferov1970}.

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Hall, Fenner, Kingsley, Soltys, and Carlson}{Hall et~al.}{1962}]{Hall1962}
Hall, R.~N., G.~E. Fenner, J.~D. Kingsley, T.~J. Soltys, and R.~O. Carlson.
\newblock Coherent light emission from {Ga--As} junctions.
\newblock \textit{Physics Review Letters}, 9(9):366--8, 1962.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Nathan, Dumke, Burns, Dill, and Lasher}{Nathan et~al.}{1962}]{Nathan1962}
Nathan, M., W.~Dumke, G.~Burns, F.~Dill, and G.~Lasher.
\newblock Stimulated emission of radiation from {GaAs P--N} junctions.
\newblock \textit{Applied Physics Letters}, 1(3):62--4, 1962.

\bibitem[Holonyak and Bevacqua(1962)]{Holonyak1962}
Holonyak, N. and S.~F. Bevacqua.
\newblock Coherent (visible) light emission from {$\textrm{Ga}(\textrm{As}_{1 - x}\textrm{P}_x)$} junctions.
\newblock \textit{Applied Physics Letters}, 1(4):82--3, 1962.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Quist, Rediker, Keyes, Krag, Lax, and
  Zeigler}{Quist et~al.}{1962}]{Quist1962}
Quist, T.~M., R.~H. Rediker, R.~J. Keyes, W.~E. Krag, B.~Lax, A.~L. McWhorter, and H.~J. Zeigler.
\newblock Semiconductor maser of {GaAs}.
\newblock \textit{Applied Physics Letters}, 1(4):91--2, 1962.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Alferov, Andreev, Portnoi, and Turkan}{Alferov et~al.}{1970}]{Alferov1970}
Alferov, Zh.~I., V.~M. Andreev, E.~L. Portnoi, and M.~K. Turkan.
\newblock {AlAs--GaAs} heterojunction injection lasers with a low room-temperature threshold.
\newblock \textit{Soviet Physics Semiconductors}, \hbox{3:460--3}, 1970.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I tried to modify on the below, but I am not able to modify

```
\def\hyper@natlinkstart#1{%
  \Hy@backout{#1}%
  \hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.#1}%
  \def\hyper@nat@current{#1}%
}
```

In the below image I have highlighted the broken links

Please check and advise how to rectify the broken link issue

[image]

Comment: This will works if you use PDFLaTeX instead of dvips, PS2PDF...

Comment: @ MadyYuvi, is possible to do through dvips method?

Comment: This problem related with dvips driver mode, hope till now it was not fixed, but some one may know how to fix it, will wait for better suggestions...

Comment: @ MadyYuvi, at the same time it is working for toc entries is more than one line

Comment: Hmmm, then will check and get back...

Comment: sorry, I don't get what's incorrect in your screenshot. "Nathan, Dumke, Burns, Dill, and Lasher (1962)" is supposed to look how?

Comment: Make a bug report to the maintainer of hypdvips.

Comment: @ sheß, there is a missing link in that place when the author name breaking in to more than a line, there is a issue in the PDF, hyperlink was missing

Comment: I cant run your mwe to test but have you tried \usepackage[emptypagelabels=false,quadpoints=false]{hypdvips}

Comment: @KJO, I tried both options, the issue not sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution and simply modified in the natbib package

i changed \NAT@hyper@ to \hyper@@link{}{cite.@citeb@extra@b@citeb} to get the break links

```
  \def\NAT@citex%
  [#1][#2]#3{%
  \NAT@reset@parser
  \NAT@sort@cites{#3}%
  \NAT@reset@citea
  \@cite{\let\NAT@nm\@empty\let\NAT@year\@empty
    \@for\@citeb:=\NAT@cite@list\do
    {\@safe@activestrue
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \@safe@activesfalse
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\@citea%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
                 \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}\def\NAT@date{}}%
     {\let\NAT@last@nm=\NAT@nm\let\NAT@last@yr=\NAT@year
      \NAT@parse{\@citeb}%
      \ifNAT@longnames\@ifundefined{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{%
        \let\NAT@name=\NAT@all@names
        \global\@namedef{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{}}{}%
      \fi
     \ifNAT@full\let\NAT@nm\NAT@all@names\else
       \let\NAT@nm\NAT@name\fi
     \ifNAT@swa\ifcase\NAT@ctype
       \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         \@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}\NAT@date}%
       \else
         \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
            \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
              \def\NAT@temp{{?}}%
              \ifx\NAT@temp\NAT@exlab\PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}%
               {Multiple citation on page \thepage: same authors and
               year\MessageBreak without distinguishing extra
               letter,\MessageBreak appears as question mark}\fi
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@exlab}%
            \else\unskip\NAT@spacechar
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
            \fi
         \else
           \@citea\hyper@@link{}{cite.\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%%%%changed to \hyper@@link
               \NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar%
               \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
         \fi
       \fi
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@alias}%
     \fi \NAT@def@citea
     \else
       \ifcase\NAT@ctype
        \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
          \@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
        \else
         \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
            \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
              \def\NAT@temp{{?}}%
              \ifx\NAT@temp\NAT@exlab\PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}%
               {Multiple citation on page \thepage: same authors and
               year\MessageBreak without distinguishing extra
               letter,\MessageBreak appears as question mark}\fi
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@exlab}%
            \else
              \unskip\NAT@spacechar
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
            \fi
         \else
           \@citea{%
             \hyper@@link{}{cite.\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%%%%%changed to \hyper@@link
             {\NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi}%
             %  {\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
             \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
           }%
         \fi
        \fi
       \or\@citea\hyper@@link{}{cite.\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%%%%%changed to \hyper@@link
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@alias}%
       \fi
       \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         \NAT@def@citea
       \else
         \NAT@def@citea@close
       \fi
     \fi
     }}\ifNAT@swa\else\if*#2*\else\NAT@cmt#2\fi
     \if\relax\NAT@date\relax\else\NAT@@close\fi\fi}{#1}{#2}}
```

Comment: Well try...keep going...